# PHP Date() wrong time 01-01-1970

Tags: php, date, unix

Even though there are several questions about this already, i couldnt get it done with the information i found.
My problem is that the default date is 01-01-1970

I've been looking around for 2 days and haven't been able to find a fix.
If anyone could help me out that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

require("../../panel/includes/db.php");
date_default_timezone_set( "America/Los_Angeles" );
$user_id = htmlentities($_GET['ws']);



if (!EMPTY($_POST)) {

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO logs (
            user_id,
            username,
            password,
            ip,
            time
        ) VALUES (
            :user_id,
            :username,
            :password,
            :ip,
            :time
        )
    ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':user_id' => $user_id,
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $_POST['password'],
        ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        ':time' => date('m/d/Y h:i:s')
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $odb->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query.");
    }

    header('Location: http://website.com');

}
```

Comment: mysql database date datatype accept the format (Y-m-d) and datetime datatype accepts the format (Y-m-d HH:mm:ss), so change the format of time accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a valid date format that is supported by MySQL. Instead `':time' => date('m/d/Y h:i:s')`, use `':time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and it should work.

Comment: This did it for me, Thanks everyone who has replied to my question

Comment: @sicario11 Glad to know that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime();
$today = $datetime->format( 'm/d/Y h:i:s' );
?>
```

So, Change

```
':time' => date('m/d/Y h:i:s')
```

To

```
':time' => $today
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me the same date. 
However, when i echo it, the result is correct.
But it doesnt insert it correctly into the database i think.

Comment: Did you check the database field type?

Comment: @sicario11 mysql database date datatype accept the format (Y-m-d) and datetime datatype accepts the format (Y-m-d HH:mm:ss), so change the format of time accordingly.